# Spring Boot integration tests using H2 in MODE=Oracle can't validate schema

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

We have a Spring Boot application which uses Oracle in production but in-memory H2 database for the integration tests. We initialize the H2 database by running Liquibase migration scripts. Time to time we have some DB incompatibility issues, for example Oracle can't store empty string etc.. I tried to mitigate some of them by connecting to H2 DB using MODE=Oracle in the connection string, the settings looks like this:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle`

After startup we check that the DB schema is migrated properly by setting
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`

However I get an exception here, because H2 uses `Timestamp` date type where the `Date` type should be used. The H2 documentation says it is a desired behavior

http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility

I checked both Oracle and H2 databases and indeed the Oracle uses Date and H2 uses Timestamp. This however causes and exception being thrown when the integration test starts and Hibernate is validating schema, the exception looks like:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [my_column] in table [my_table];
 found [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)], but expecting [date (Types#DATE)]
```

I have two questions:

Why can't H2 use `Date` in Oracle mode, but uses it in a default mode? This should be a question for H2 devs, but I'd appreciate the answer if anyone knows.

Is there any way how to test `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` and `MODE=Oracle` at the same time? I think I can have one test to validate the schema and other tests running in Oracle mode, but that's far from being a nice solution.

**Edit:** H2 version is '1.4.199'

Comment: Which version of H2?  In my existing projects I'm using v1.4.200 instead of 2.x to avoid compatibility problems.  In one project I'm using v1.4.196 because newer ones give a timestamp/date problem.  I have not yet tried to modify my code to be compatible with 2.x.

Comment: @Pino Good question - '1.4.199'

Comment: Try with 1.4.196 and let me know.

Comment: @Pino That's working, thanks. I'll play with the versions a bit so I'm not stuck on one version without being able to upgrade.

Comment: I think you should run your integration tests against the actual database you use, Oracle. [TestContainers](https://testcontainers.com) is a solution for that. It integrates nicely with Spring Boot testing and the Spring folks have documented it nicely.  If you really need to use H2 then use a DDL abstraction layer such as [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/). (there will be other benefits to that too, for example in relation to future evolution of your database model). Liquibase will abstract away the difference you mention.